# Syntax error in JavaScript typeof

Tags: javascript

Hello guys I'm having trouble with the following JS code:

```
 function <%=this.ClientID%>_CerrarClick()
    {
        if (typeof(<%=FuncionCerrar%>**)** == "function")
            <%=FuncionCerrar%>;
        return false;
    }
```

I need help to find out why that function throw syntax error.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to mix it with ASP.NET code. What does the *actual* rendered JavaScript look like?

Comment: ... and Markdown, if the `** **` means anything.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/sigozaputeci/1/edit see for yourself in this link. use jsbin or jsfiddle site to debug javascript

Comment: That code is very error-prone and fragile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `()`

```
function <%=this.ClientID%>_CerrarClick()
    {
        if (typeof(<%=FuncionCerrar%>) === "function")
            <%=FuncionCerrar%>();
        return false;
    }
```

Edit

if `FuncionCerrar` is `xx()` then

```
var a='<%=FuncionCerrar%>';
    a=a.replace('()','');

 function <%=this.ClientID%>_CerrarClick()
        {
            if (typeof(a) === "function")
                a();
            return false;
        }
```

Assuming you do have function named `<%=FuncionCerrar%>` in your code. if you're not sure then :

`if (typeof(window.<%=FuncionCerrar%>) === "function")`

Comment: @ArnoldSandíCalderón just add `alert(<%=FuncionCerrar%>)` and tell me what is the result